# Nativescript how to use hooks

Tags: nativescript

Can you please share any blog / link, which walk thorugh the step how and where to user hooks in nativescript?
Also how can i include enviornment config depending on app environment  while building / debugging and bundling.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [README.md of the nativescript-hooks](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-hook) plugin